# "alternatives=true" not working in Google Direction API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using Google's Direction API to draw a driving path between source and destination. I want to show multiple alternative routes so I pass the parameter 
`alternatives=true` in the URL string. But it doesn't displays any extra path but only one.
My code for the URL :

```
Private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest)
{
    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    //Adding Alternative parameter
    String alternative = "alternatives=true";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+alternative;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> alternatives — If set to true, specifies that the Directions service
>   **may** provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that
>   providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the
>   server.

You will not always get alternatives!

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Comment: Can you please elaborate why? Is it because of restrictions imposed on specific areas of slow response from servers?

Comment: @RajaShahrozeAbbas I am not sure why they may not always send alternatives, but It could be due to many reasons, maybe there is no alternative or may be they are restricting it on the free usage package which many limitations on your usage See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits)